# How to prove that as an $R$-module, $\mathbb{C}^n$ is finitely generated iff $R=\mathbb{C}[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Consider the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $M=\mathbb{C}^n$. I am trying
>   to prove that as an $R$-module, $M$ is finitely generated
>   iff $R=\mathbb{C}[x]$.

Suppose first that $R=\mathbb{C}[x]$. Since $M$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-module, we know that the V.S. basis $B=\{m_1, ..., m_n\}$ would also generate $M$. This means there are numbers $c_1,\dots, c_{n}\in \mathbb{C}$ such that given any $m\in M$, we can write $$m=c_1m_1+\cdots+c_{n}m_{n}.
$$ However, the $c_{i}$'s are also constant polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ so we get that $B$ is a finite generating set for the $R$-module $M$.

I don't know how to prove the converse and would appreciate some help.

Edit: This exercise arose from the following notes I am reading:
[image]

Comment: Is this true?  What about $\mathbb C[X]$ as a module over itself?  It is not a finite dimensional vector space.

Comment: @D_S I'm betting that the author is assuming that $X$ has some internal multiplication structure, such as pointwise multiplication.

Comment: J. Doe, would you mind including the author's definition of $\mathbb{C}[X]$?

Comment: @Anonymous: Please consider looking here (the exercise is on page 20): https://www.math.ru.nl/~tcrisp/teaching/crisp_497B.pdf

Comment: @J.Doe Ah, the definition of $M$ as a $\mathbb{C}[X]$-module is on page 15. Also, the author is being very sloppy in the example and exercise by using $X$ to refer to two different things.

Comment: @Anonymous: There is a disclaimer in the beginning of the notes regarding this sloppy-ness.

Comment: @D_S: I don't understand your comment. I just started learning about this stuff so please excuse my ignorance, but why are we looking at $\mathbb{C}[x]$ as a counter example? I know that as a module over itself, $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is f.g. of rank $1$, but is infinite-dimensional as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces. I don't get why this makes you doubt the statement isn't true. We're specifically only talking about $M=\mathbb{C}^n$ here so idk...

Comment: Exercise is saying, in particular, that every fin. generated $\mathbb C[X]$-module is finite dimensional as a $\mathbb C$-vector space, which is false.

Comment: @D_S: It was confusingly worded exercise for me, but thank you: I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As D_S noted, the converse is false. Let $M=\mathbb{C}[X]$, the free $\mathbb{C}[X]$-module of rank $1$. Then no module of the form in the example is isomorphic to $M$. To see this, let $N=\mathbb{C}^n$ be any $\mathbb{C}[X]$-module with respect to some linear transformation $T:\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}^n$. Then there is some polynomial on which $T$ is $0$ (such as the characteristic polynomial). Say $a_0+a_1T+\cdots+a_mT^m=0$. Then $a_0+a_1X+\cdots+a_mX^m$ is an element of $\mathbb{C}[X]$ which annihilates $N$ since for any $v\in N$, we have $$(a_0+a_1X+\cdots+ a_mX^m)\cdot v=a_0v+a_1T(v)+\cdots+a_mT^m(v)=0$$ and therefore $N$ is not a free module. Consequently, $N\not\cong M$.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the result: Over a PID f.g. modules are torsion free iff they are free. After this, I think I understand your answer. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @J.Doe I did not need to use the full strength of that theorem actually. Free modules are clearly torsion free over any commutative ring (the converse was not used in my proof). I showed that $N$ is not torsion free and therefore cannot be a free module.